# Required module 'Yojson' is unavailable without location

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind

I am trying to build a simple program using `Yojson`: the `main.ml` file is just

```
let () = exit 1;
```

and an `mod.ml` file contains

```
open Yojson
open Yojson.Basic.Util
let rec json_to_tree json = 
        let _ = json |> member "key" in
        ()
```

I have a Makefile which first compiles `.ml` files, then links. For simplicity, let assume we run the three following commands:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package yojson -g  -c mod.ml
ocamlfind ocamlc -package yojson -g  -c main.ml
ocamlfind ocamlc -package yojson -g  -o inter  mod.cmo main.cmo
```

The problem is that the linking part produces the following error:

```
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Required module `Yojson' is unavailable
```

which I have no idea to solve. Using the `Unix` module can lead to similar error which are resolved adding `unix.cma` when linking, but this doesn't help for Yojson.

For the sake of completeness, I installed `yojson` via opam, and `ocamlfind list | grep yojson` returns

```
yojson              (version: 1.3.3)
yojson.biniou       (version: 1.3.3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package yojson -linkpkg -g -o inter mod.cmo main.cmo
```

While this works, `https://github.com/ocaml/dune` is the better option to building ocaml code.